# UglifyJs Webpack Plugin fails on production

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

so I installed the latest version of UglifyJs Plugin (2.0.1) and I believe I imported it correctly. but now when I do npm run production this is the error I'm getting:

> ValidationError: UglifyJs Plugin Invalid Options options should NOT have additional properties

So I googled the error and  majority of the topics I found where talking about changing the version. But most of them were pretty old so like they were talking about upgrading to 1.1.9 and etc.

This is the plugin settings in my webpack.config.js file settings

```
    const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        },
        sourceMap: true
    }));
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: 3.6.0 sorry I completely forgot to mention that

Comment: Any ideas? is the webpack version causing issues with the plugin? should I be using a different version of the plugin? Thanks

Comment: 2.0.1 is for webpack 4, you need to downgrade your plugin version. or upgrade webpack to the latest one

Comment: This is a silly question, but how do I downgrade UglifyJs? I can't find a command for yarn to download the previous versions

Comment: have to look at the releases, probably a major release, around 1.x.x, and manually change your package.json

Comment: try v1.3.0, put that on package.json and run yarn again